# Как связать два html с ajax функциями на одной странице?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Страница разбита на две части, в верхней меню(кнопка) в нижней появляется результат нажатия меню. Как в верхней так и в нижней части испльзуется ajax и собственно в нижнем окне он глючит...Я так понимаю крнфлик какой-то? Как связать в одном окне несколько "фреймов" с разными функциями ajax? их надо как-то обрабатывать в одном файле?

Index.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#button").click(function(){
        $('#body').load("info.jsp");
          });
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">go</button>
<hr>
<div id = body></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Info.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("div").animate({
                    height: 'toggle'
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button multiple times to toggle the animation.</p>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы прямо так 2 html засунули? их надо разбить на 2 файла и вставить в один общий, то есть в итоге должно получиться 3 html файла. Но вам будет проблематично прокидывать из одного в другой информацию, лучше полностью изменить подход и делать все на одной странице

Comment: Сори, крыво вставил. У меня два файла. Index оснойвной и в в нем есть div в который я загружаю втрой: "Info.jsp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В динамически подгруженном `html` нельзя запускать `js`. Для подвешивания событий на динамические элементы необходимо использовать `.on()`.

Index.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $('#body').load("info.jsp");
        });
        $(document).on("click", "#start", function(){
            $("#animateDiv").animate({
                height: 'toggle'
            });
        });
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">go</button>
<hr>
<div id = body></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Info.jsp

```
<p>Click the button multiple times to toggle the animation.</p>
<button id="start">Start Animation</button>
<div id="animateDiv" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, именно то что искал.

Comment: Не подскажете как вы полнить в info вот такую функцию? `   $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );`

Comment: Нет, c `DataTable` не знаком. Но если она в Info.jsp, то видимо сюда: `$('#body').load("info.jsp", function() { ...... });`

Comment: Дивно. Работает но только при первом переходе. При повторном нажатии на #body функция не выполняется.

Comment: DataTable() это отдельная js библиотека ее подгрузить надо в index или info? `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">`

Comment: кажется что-то нашел...

Comment: весь js, в том числе ссылки на сторонние js можно ставить только в в index.jsp